# Can't seem to open a JBoss Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a project called DBankOnline , and I used Eclipse+tomcat to work on the project and it was working fine, When I tried to move my project to 'JBoss developer studio' it doesn't work. When I try to run the JBoss server I dont get exceptions, but when I try to open the server in the browser with 'localhost:8080' i get "page not found" message , Here is what I get when I try to start the server.

```
13:50:37,918 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
13:50:39,419 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
13:50:39,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
13:50:45,187 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using     socket-binding (management-http)
13:50:45,192 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
13:50:45,271 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
13:50:45,307 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
13:50:45,428 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
13:50:45,437 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan     subsystem.
13:50:45,440 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
13:50:45,455 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
13:50:45,478 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
13:50:46,717 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox     version=4.0.7.Final
13:50:46,713 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA     Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
13:50:47,984 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool --     27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
13:50:48,003 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011802: Starting Naming     Service
13:50:48,433 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail     session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:50:49,701 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting     Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
13:50:49,949 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-2)     JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
13:50:50,763 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012:     Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\isgav\Desktop\Java programing\jboss-as-    7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
13:50:50,817 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on     localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
13:50:50,801 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on     /127.0.0.1:9999
13:50:50,834 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1)     JBAS015003: Found DBankOnline2.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file     called DBankOnline2.war.dodeploy
13:50:51,115 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3)     JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
13:50:51,278 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting     deployment of "DBankOnline2.war"
13:50:52,620 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010403:     Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 4.0)
13:50:52,812 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) The     listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The     duplicate definition has been ignored.
13:50:52,932 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1)     Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/DBankOnline2'
13:50:55,924 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) Hibernate     Validator 4.2.0.Final
13:50:56,466 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS018210: Registering web context:     /DBankOnline2
13:50:56,487 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on     http://127.0.0.1:9990
13:50:56,489 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final     "Brontes" started in 20902ms - Started 183 of 260 services (76 services are passive or on-demand)
13:50:56,684 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed     "DBankOnline2.war"
```

-thank you

Comment: Try localhost:8080/DBankOnline2
    `13:50:56,466 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS018210: Registering web context:     /DBankOnline2`

Comment: Do you have an `index` file, configured the welcome-file and verified that the configured welcome file is part of the deployed package?